Dismiss SearchAnchor's search suggestions by dragging / panning
Given the following code sample, you'll notice that you can't interact with the slider until the search suggestions are dismissed. Dismissing the suggestions can be accomplished either by tapping the arrow button or tapping outside the search UI, but dragging doesn't dismiss the suggestions. I see that opening the search suggestions pushes a new navigator route, and I assume this new route is what prevents interaction with the slider.
Ideally the search suggestions could remain open while the user interacts with the slider. Short of that, I'd prefer that the search suggestions dismiss when dragging outside (like it does when tapping outside).

Is there a way to dismiss the search suggestions when the user drags/pans?
Is there a way to allow interaction with the slider while search suggestions are shown?

FWIW, I've been testing using a mouse on Flutter-web.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SearchBarApp());

class SearchBarApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchBarApp> createState() => _SearchBarAppState();
}

class _SearchBarAppState extends State<SearchBarApp> {
  double sliderValue = 0.2;
  SearchController searchController = SearchController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => searchController.openView(),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SearchAnchor(
                searchController: searchController,
                builder: (_, SearchController controller) {
                  return SearchBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    onTap: () {
                      controller.openView();
                    },
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      controller.openView();
                    },
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  );
                },
                suggestionsBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
                  return List<ListTile>.generate(5, (int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('item $index'),
                      onTap: () {},
                    );
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Slider(
                value: sliderValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    sliderValue = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

